# Blank notification after applying to job on Stack Overflow jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

[image]

I filled out the form to apply on the careers site, hit the apply button, and got this.

There is no way to click out of it or continue.

Here are the errors I receive:

[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors on your javascript console?

Comment: yup. See new answer as I can't paste it in here.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to verify that this happened because your ad blocking extension filtered our `http://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/analytics.min.js` file.

We're no longer using that particular file, so this shouldn't be an issue anymore.