# Dialog after submitting cover letter is way too high to see content

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface

Inspect elements shows the actual content (i.e. it just failed to display content correctly)

[image: Screenshot]

The dialog is way too high to see any content.

To reproduce this problem:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/107008/senior-moblie-engineer-getsocial-bv or any other jobs that lets you directly apply here
2. Scroll up and down (e.g. read the skills & requirements while writing the cover letter)
3. Submit

Comment: What dialog? What were you trying to do? What browser are you using, on what device?

Comment: oops forgot to mention i will edit the post now

Comment: Any errors on the Javascript console? do you have an ad blocker? does it happen without the ad blocker enabled?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WXiK.png

Comment: @GervasioMarchand I forgot to jot it down, and I can't just reproduce it (it's a job application) I only remember in the console I saw text that said job application successful. and also i do have ublock enable at that time

Comment: excellent, thanks for that :) I'm trying to replicate and I'll get back to you

Comment: @LouisTsai do you have any 3rd-party filters enabled other than the ones that come by default?

Comment: @LouisTsai see [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335857/920295) on the initial report of this issue